# How to get static container background but scrollable loginform?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I want to scroll the loginform but NOT the background, but i noticed that the cointaner that contains these "circles" are moved to the up when keyboards appears, so i added

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
```

To the scaffold, but now i cant scroll anything in the loginform and thats is what i dont want, i want to scroll ONLY the loggin form..

[Here is the screenshot of the emulator, just click this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zl1r.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:landscapes/bloc/inherited_provider.dart';
import 'package:landscapes/bloc/login_bloc.dart';
import 'package:landscapes/pages/register_page.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        body: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              _crearFondo(),
              _loginForm(context),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget _crearFondo() {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final fondoGris = Container(
        height: size.height, width: size.width, color: Colors.grey[850]);
    final circulo = Container(
      width: 90.0,
      height: 90.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
          color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.05)),
    );
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        fondoGris,
        Positioned(top: 50.0, left: 30.0, child: circulo),
        Positioned(top: 150.0, right: 50.0, child: circulo),
        Positioned(bottom: 180.0, right: 20.0, child: circulo),
        Positioned(bottom: 280.0, left: 40.0, child: circulo),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _loginForm(context) {
    final bloc = InheritedProvider.loginBlocInherit(context);
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SafeArea(child: Container(height: size.height * 0.05)),
          SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.05),
          welcomeBackForm(),
          SizedBox(height: 55.0),
          _formEmail(bloc),
          SizedBox(height: 30.0),
          _formPassword(),
          SizedBox(height: 38),
          _button(),
          SizedBox(height: 50),
          _crearCuenta(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  //MENSAJE BIENVENIDA
  Widget welcomeBackForm() {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
      child: Text(
        'Hello!\nWelcome back',
        style: GoogleFonts.playfairDisplay(
            fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }

  //TEXTFORMFIELD DEL EMAIL
  Widget _formEmail(LoginBloc bloc) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.email,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            hintText: 'Email adress',
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Colors.grey[600],
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none)),
        style: TextStyle(height: 1),
        validator: (value) {
          Pattern pattern =
              r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
          RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);

          if (regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
            return null;
          } else {
            return ('El email no es correcto');
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  //TEXTFORMFIELD DEL PASSWORD
  Widget _formPassword() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.lock,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          hintText: 'Password',
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.grey[600],
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none),
        ),
        style: TextStyle(height: 1),
      ),
    );
  }

  //BOTON INGRESAR
  Widget _button() {
    return RaisedButton(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(254, 200, 140, 1),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 90.0, vertical: 15.0),
      child: Text('ingresar'),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
      ),
      elevation: 0.0,
      onPressed: () => _submit(),
    );
  }

  //FLATBUTTON DE CREAR CUENTA
  Widget _crearCuenta() {
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'registerpage'),
      child: Text(
        'Crear una nueva cuenta',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
      ),
      textColor: Colors.white,
    );
  }

  //SUBMIT DEL BOTON
  void _submit() async {
    if (!formKey.currentState.validate()) return null;
    formKey.currentState.save();

    Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => RegisterPage()));
    // Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, HomePage.routName).then((value) { setState(() { });});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try wrapping your _loginForm with [**SingleChildScrollView**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) as follows :

```
SingleChildScrollView(child: _loginForm(context)),
```

By doing so the widgets within _crearFondo() will not scroll, however the widgets within _loginForm will scroll.

Please review the Flutter Documentation for [**SingleChildScrollView**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html)

> **SingleChildScrollView**
>
> A box in which a single widget can be scrolled.
>
> This widget is useful when you have a single box that will normally be
> entirely visible, for example a clock face in a time picker, but you
> need to make sure it can be scrolled if the container gets too small
> in one axis (the scroll direction).
>
> It is also useful if you need to shrink-wrap in both axes (the main
> scrolling direction as well as the cross axis), as one might see in a
> dialog or pop-up menu. In that case, you might pair the
> SingleChildScrollView with a ListBody child.
>
> When you have a list of children and do not require cross-axis
> shrink-wrapping behavior, for example a scrolling list that is always
> the width of the screen, consider ListView, which is vastly more
> efficient that a SingleChildScrollView containing a ListBody or Column
> with many children.